# Why is the load more content button on my project not working please?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi all this is driving me nuts - I have a load more content button on my site, I had it on my previous site version and it worked absolutely fine. I have only changed the design of my content (I now have cards instead of just clickable images). When I click on the button the screen scrolls but the content is not displayed, I think the problem lies with the way I have the 'div class more' set out, but after trying many different variations I am still only getting the same result. Any thoughts on this would be massively appreciated.

```js
   

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("more").slice(0, 6).show();
        $("#LoadMore").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("more:hidden").slice(0, 6).slideDown();
            if ($("more:hidden").length == 0) {
                $("#LoadMore").fadeOut('slow');
            }
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 1500);
           // $('#LoadMore').hide(); 
           // document.getElementById('LoadMore').setAttribute("style","display:none");
        });
    });
```

```css
    #LoadMore {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 14px 50px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
      background: #dd0a37;
      color: #FFF;
      box-shadow: 8px 8px 4px #e8e5e5;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
      transition: 0.3s all;
    }

    #LoadMore:hover, #LoadMore:focus {
      color: #fff;
      background: #112036;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .more {
      display:none;
    }

/* Float four columns side by side */
.profile-column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}


/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.row {margin: 0 -5px;}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .profile-column {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <!-- BUTTON -->
    <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#" id="LoadMore" class="main-btn" style="margin-top: 50px;">Ver Mais</a>
        </div>  
      
    <!--CONTENT I WANT TO LOAD -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="more">
                <div class="profile-column">
                   <div class="profile-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tim-v">                              
                    <img src="img/speakers/comp/tim-v.jpg" alt="for salesshaker and lead-results.com" class="img-raised rounded img-fluid image">
                    <h4 class="profile-title">name</h4>
                    <p class="profile-company">company</p>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="more">
               <div class="profile-column">
                  <div class="profile-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dr-phil">
                    <img src="img/speakers/comp/dr-phil.jpg" alt="for salesshaker and lead-results.com" class="img-raised rounded img-fluid image">
                    <h4 class="profile-title">name</h4>
                    <p class="profile-company">company</p><br>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="more">
              <div class="profile-column">
                <div class="profile-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fab-r">
                  <img src="img/speakers/comp/fab-r.jpg" alt="for salesshaker and lead-results.com" class="img-raised rounded img-fluid image">
                  <h4 class="profile-title">name</h4>
                  <p class="profile-company">company</p><br>        
                </div>
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="more">                  
                <div class="profile-column">
                    <div class="profile-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ludo-r">
                        <img src="img/speakers/comp/ludo.jpg" alt="for salesshaker and lead-results.com" class="img-raised rounded img-fluid image">
                          <h4 class="profile-title">name</h4>
                          <p class="profile-company">company</p><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="more">
                <div class="profile-column">
                    <div class="profile-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tim-c">
                        <img src="img/speakers/comp/tim-c.jpg" alt="for salesshaker and lead-results.com" class="img-raised rounded img-fluid image">
                        <h4 class="profile-title">name</h4>
                        <p class="profile-company">company</p><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="more">                      
                <div class="profile-column">
                    <div class="profile-card" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#becky-b">
                        <img src="img/speakers/comp/becky.jpg" alt="for salesshaker and lead-results.com" class="img-raised rounded img-fluid image">
                        <h4 class="profile-title-r">name</h4>
                        <p class="profile-company">company</p><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: because you have to add jquery

Comment: sorry my bad, I should have also said that I have <script>jquery.min.js</script> as one of my plugins at the bottom of my page already and it doesn't make a difference which  I add it - the result is still the same

Comment: sorry for late answer. it was midnight in our country so I had to sleep... I edited the previous answer. I hope it will solve your problem. If not comment me . tnx